# Simplest script for Greasemonkey or Stylish to select “100 Results” from the “Results per page:” dropdown menu in Google’s Advanced Search page?

Tags: search, greasemonkey, stylish

Can anybody come up with the simplest script for Greasemonkey or Stylish to select “100 Results” from the “Results per page:” dropdown menu in Google’s Advanced Search page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) script that works on this URL: http://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en.  It may work for other languages, but I only tested it with the above URL.

```
var nums = document.getElementsByName("num");
if(nums.length > 0) {
  nums[0].value = 100;
  nums[0].selected = "selected";
}
```

Comment: How? I clicked the up arrow, but it didn't take it. Apparently, I haven't been here long enough.

Comment: Yes, you need 15 reputation to cast an upvote.  However, you can click the checkmark below the voting block to mark an answer as "accepted."  This will give the answerer 15 reputation and the asker 2 reputation.  It's a win/win!